# why gui is crashing when setting a value in the first column of tablewidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have `QTableWidget` in my UI. The first column is a set of `QRadioButton`s. Here is how it looks:
[image]

I've added the following code to the `MainWindow` constructor:

```
for (char i = 0; i < ui->currentSetting1TableWidget->rowCount(); i++)
      ui->currentSetting1TableWidget->setCellWidget(i, 0, new QRadioButton(ui->currentSetting1TableWidget));
```

I've also added the following code:

```
void MainWindow::on_currentSetting1TableWidget_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QRadioButton *b = (QRadioButton *)ui->currentSetting1TableWidget->cellWidget(index.row(), 1);
    b->setChecked(true);
}
```

My code is crashing when it executes  `b->setChecked(true);`. I assume it has something to do with me not properly understanding what casting in `C++` and what exactly is returned by `cellWidget` in `Qt`. I tried to investigate it but I can't see what the problem is. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see if you get a more specific error? Also you should probably check if `b` points to a valid object before trying to call any function on it. (And I'd recommend using C++ style casts over C style casts)

Comment: ***QRadioButton *b = (QRadioButton *)ui->currentSetting1TableWidget->cellWidget(index.row(), 1);*** maybe the cell widget is not a radiobutton. I would use `QRadioButton *b =qobject_cast<QRadioButton*>(currentSetting1TableWidget->cellWidget(index.row(), 1))` and check the returned pointer for nullptr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`qobject_cast`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.8/qobject.html#qobject_cast)/`dynamic_cast` for casting types derived from `QObject` and check the returned value.

You seem to be setting cell widget in column 0, but you're accessing it from column 1. It may very well return `nullptr` right away, from looking at your screenshot.